# Is there a way to move the VMware Player's toolbar to a different edge of the screen?

Tags: vmware-player

I am using VMware Player 7.1.2, and when the virtual machine is running in full-screen mode, there is a toolbar located at the top of the screen.  Is there a way to move the toolbar to show up at a different edge of the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to move the toolbar to a different edge of the screen.  If the toolbar edge is getting in your way, you can edit `%APPDATA%\VMware\preferences.ini` and add the line:

```
pref.vmplayer.fullscreen.autohideSize = "0"
```

Comment: What does this do exactly?

Comment: @EgeErsoz It sets the size of the toolbar edge when the toolbar is hidden.